# Retrieve POST checkbox data from form if they exist

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Hello knowledgeable people. I am having trouble retrieving checkbox data from form. I have a site in which user can add checkboxes themselves, so I am writing them out like this:

```
<table style="padding:10px;">
            <?php

            $query_boolean = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM moduls WHERE type='boolean'") or die(mysql_error());
            $query_boolean->execute();
            while (($row = $query_boolean->fetch()) != false)
                {

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $row->name ?>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            $s = "";

                            $s .= sprintf('<input type="checkbox" class="textbox" name="boolean_%s" value="yes">%s', $row->id, Yes);
                            $s .= sprintf('<input type="checkbox" class="textbox" name="boolean_%s" value="no">%s', $row->id, No);

                            echo $s;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                    }
                    ?>


            </table>
```

Now I have an advanced search in which I have to chech through every checkbox to see what has been selected (ether none, Yes, No, or both). How can I get the info from every checkbox in variables? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To get POST data from checkboxes they must have attribute

> checked="checked"

EDIT:
If you have 2 checkbox as this..

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="textbox" name="boolean_yes" value="yes">
<input type="checkbox" class="textbox" name="boolean_no" value="no">
```

When you submit your form the checkbox with attribute checked will be sent as POST and the one without checked attribute will not be sent..

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $all_checked = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
       if(strpos($key, "boolean_") > -1){
          $all_checked[$key] = $value;
       }
    }

    var_dump($all_checked);
}
```

This way you will get inside $all_checked array all marked boxes.. All others checboxes are not marked!

Comment: I do not understand. How do I check which one has the atribute checked and where?

Comment: Checked is when user mark checkbox , if its not marked its not sent as POST

Comment: Ok, so what code should I write to get the data (which ones were checked)    Sterile environment: Yes  No
Missing data: Yes  No and so on...

Comment: In your PHP you will get POST only for those checkboxes which are marked.. At your PHP code you can write some thing as if there is no POST then its not checked, and if there is post is checked..

Comment: ok I understand...but I don't know how to write the code...my checkbox names are boolean_1, boolean_4, boolean_14,... and there are many of them because user can add them. So I don't know, maybe I have to make a foreach statement? But how can I write foreach($_POST['boolean_%s'] as $boolean_%s). Do you understand?

Comment: Where you are processing the POST data ?

Comment: I am not...because I don't know how to...now it's just: if(isset($_POST['search'])) {  }, which checks if the button has been pressed

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get checkbox value then use checkbox name as array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email1[]" value="">
```

an get it on another page by

```
<?php

$var2 = $_POST['email1'];
$v=implode(",",$var2);

echo $v;
?>
```

try it